# Thinking Sphinx "no field found in schema" error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am pretty new to Sphinx.

Trying to find user with name "bob" and company_id "14".

```
Controller:
@users = User.search 'bob', :conditions => { :company_id => '14'}

Model:
  define_index do
    indexes :name
    indexes :company_id
  end

Error:
index user_core: query error: no field 'company_id' found in schema
```

I have the 'company_id' in table & I re-indexed everything several times.
When I am just searching for the 'name' everything works properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes should be declared as:

```
has company_id
```

So, in you case:

```
Model:
define_index do
    indexes :name
    has :company_id
  end
```

Comment: yes, exactly, then you can search with help of **with** like Model.search('bob', :with => {:company_id => '14'})

Answer (score 4):

Just as another helpful hint: turns out I had to change the way I called `Model.search()`, since my field was listed as an attribute (i.e. using `has`), I needed to call the `search` method with `:with` instead of `:conditions` (for fields).

Answer (score 1):

And one more helpful hint, if you happen to be an idiot like me:

If you are getting this error and you are correctly using attributes and fields, it may be that you forgot to restart your dev server after adding a new field to the index.